# Installing ceiling fan

Tags: ceiling-fan

I have an old house so when I tried to replace a ceiling fan the wires coming from the ceiling the casings fell apart. I now have bare wires is this dangerous and what can I do? Can I wraps electricians tape around them? There is no more wire to pull down.

Comment: Sounds like old  knob and tube wiring  .If you send pic may help.Wires may be to far gone and  need to be replaced,

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box please?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we can help you. And,  please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here.